# Can a jwt created in one language or library be decoded and verified in another?

Tags: node.js, go, cryptography, jwt, jwt-go

So I have an API server that uses **golang** and the **jwt-go** library to issue jwt and i want to have a **socket.io** server running using **node.js** and **jsonwebtoken** library that needs to decode and verify the token, so my question is can I issue a token from one library, decode and verify it from another?

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR: Yes.**

Interoperability is kind of the point of using JSON web tokens. [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) explicitly defines (independent of implenentation language) how JWTs are to be issued and verified and all known implementations (at least those [listed on the project website](http://jwt.io/#libraries-io)) follow this standard.

Personally, I've used [jwt-go](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go) (Go), [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) (Node.JS) and [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) (PHP) and [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home) (Java, Scala) all in conjunction and never encountered any interoperability issues.